# SELECT POPULAR POST

Tags: mysql

I have a views table which stores the `Post_id` of a post when viewed. Example

```
Id          post_id
1           1
2           3
3           1
4           5
6           5
7           1
8           1
9           2
10          3
```

I want to select the top 5 most post Id and order desc.... Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by any help? do you mean to write the code for you? Please provide us with what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
select Post_id,views from (select Post_id,count(*) views from views_table group by Post_id) t1 order by views desc limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
select * from (select post_id,count(*) count_post from views group by post_id order by 2 desc) where rownum <=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id , count(`post_id`) as tpost_id FROM `post` GROUP BY `post_id` ORDER BY tpost_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, a little explanation of your solution helps others understand how to solve these sorts of problems in the future.